# Jcommander usage formatting

Tags: java, jcommander

Hey I am using [Jcommander](http://jcommander.org) library to parse command line arguments.
My problem is with the format of the usage message generated by the Jcommander.
This is the output of the usage function:

```
 Usage: mvnUploader [options]
 Options:
 * -d, --directory
     the directory of the artifacts to upload
   -h, --help
     print help message
```

I want that the option and the description will be in the **same line**

My args class :

```
 public class OptionalArgs {

 @Parameter(names = {"-d", "--directory"}, required = true, description = 
            "the directory of the artifacts to upload")
 private String pathToArtifacts;

 @Parameter(names ={"-h", "--help"} , help = true, description = "print help 
                                                                  message")
 private boolean help = false;


 public String getPathToArtifacts() {
    return pathToArtifacts;
 }

 public boolean isHelp() {
    return help;
 }

}
```

Comment: The format of the usage method is hard-coded. You can possibly write your own subclass of `JCommander` with a different implementation of `usage()`.

Answer (score 1):

i am afraid @RealSkeptic is right. The line wrapping which bothers you is located in [JCommander.java, line 1210](https://github.com/cbeust/jcommander/blob/1.71/src/main/java/com/beust/jcommander/JCommander.java#L1210).

```
 out.append(indent).append("  "
    + (parameter.required() ? "* " : "  ")
    + pd.getNames()
    + "\n");
```

imho a custom impl. of `usage()` is to much effort as you would have to compensate about 100 lines of code from `JCommander.java`. what about a pull request introducing a configurable `UsagePrinter` class?

Comment: It seems that I dont have any other options except pull request, thanks for help :)